# MySQL Error: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded

Tags: mysql

I just installed MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22 with Homebrew on my macOS v10.13.4.
I ran the command:
`brew install mysql`

After the installation completed, as directed by Homebrew, I ran the command:
`mysql_secure_installation`
and was returned the error: `Error: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found`

I tried a few things like changing default_authentication_plugin to mysql_native_password in the my.cnf file but it still throws the same error.

Next I tried running:
`mysql_upgrade -u root`
and I was thrown the same error again `mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2059: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 5):

So, I found the running process of mysqld by `sudo lsof -i tcp:3306` then I killed it using `sudo kill -9 <PID>`.
After this I tried `$ mysql_secure_installation` again but ran into a new error `Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)`
After trying a few fixes for getting mysql.sock to work, I started the MySQL server with
`$ sudo mysql.server start`
then went ahead with `$ mysql_secure_installation` to set password for the root user.

This worked for me finally.

Note: Homebrew asks you to first do `mysql_secure_installation` before starting the MySQL server for the first time but that just made me run into endless loop of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and solved this by stopping the MySQL server 8.0 from System Preferences -> MySQL settings. I have both the 5.7 and 8.0 installed at the same time.

Now when I type

> mysql --version

I get

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for osx10.13 (x86_64)

And I can log in successfully.